# Expected argument of type "object or array", "integer" given

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm facing an error when building an form item using an entity type with a custom query. Without the custom query it worked fine... so I suppose that the problem lies somewhere in the query.

That's the excerpt from type.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Event', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'EventBundle:Event',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                        ->select('e.id, g.title')
                        ->leftJoin('e.Group g')
                        ->orderBy('e.start', 'DESC');
                },
                'property' => 'title',
                'empty_value' => 'Please choose an event...'
            ))
```

I can see that the query works fine... this are the values that create the exception.

> PropertyAccessor ->readPropertiesUntil ('77', object(PropertyPath),
>   '1') in
>   /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php
>   at line 49

Thanks for any help

Comment: A little more context here would help, I assume you're building a form for an entity that has a relation of event? If not, you might want to try `'mapped' => false`, then it won't try and map this value to the object, this'll be what the PropertyAccessor is trying to do. If you need it to do that, then my best guess is that there is something outside of this code amiss, perhaps the relation is not set up quite right.

NB: The first param is the field name, not the entity name (although it will infer the property you're mapping from it, you'd normally put it in lower snake case, `'event'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "query_builder" closure option expects an object or an array as return. Your QueryBuilder selects the Id of the Event and the title of the Group, which are not objects.
Try this:

```
$builder
        ->add('Event', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'EventBundle:Event',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('e')
                    ->select('e')
                    ->leftJoin('e.Group', 'g')
                    ->orderBy('e.start', 'DESC');
            },
            'property' => 'title',
            'empty_value' => 'Please choose an event...'
        ))
```

Comment: That was it... by using ->select('e,g') and setting property to 'Group.title' it worked. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on your Qb Statement

The definition of a leftJoin is done in this way:

```
// Example - $qb->leftJoin('u.Phonenumbers', 'p', 'WITH', 'p.area_code = 55')
public function leftJoin($join, $alias = null, $conditionType = null, $condition = null);
```

in your case you need to change:

```
->leftJoin('e.Group g')
```

to

```
->leftJoin('e.Group', 'g')
```

Comment: You're right... I changed it, but the error is still the same :-(